# Is it possible to use portals with React 15 and react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have seen that react-select supports portals (https://react-select.com/advanced#portaling) but I guess it uses React 16 portal API. I saw implementation of portals for React 15 (https://github.com/tajo/react-portal) but I am not sure that there is a way of using it with react-select at the moment.

Is there a way to integrate these two libraries together?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box seems not possible, even *react-portal* library works with *React15*, *react-select* depends on official *ReactDOM.createPortal*

(check the code in https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/2654ce0505d9e3820e169109cc413778fc20f843/src/components/Menu.js).

Possible solutions would be fork *react-select* to use *react-portal* fallback if *ReactDOM.createPortal* is undefined, and then changing his *Menu* component render function.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Portal } from 'react-portal';
....


const createPortal = ReactDOM.createPortal
  ? (child, node) => ReactDOM.createPortal(child, node)
  : (child, node) => <Portal node={node}>{child}</Portal>;

return appendTo ? createPortal(menuWrapper, appendTo) : menuWrapper;
```

I have tested using npm link over react-select local changes, with React and ReactDOM 15.4.2 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

<s>**This is just theory**</s>, but overwriting the `MenuPortal` component with your portal using the [components framework](https://react-select.com/components) may be a solution. But you may have to implement your own positioning functionality.

```
// I would recommend using a class instead of a function component, this is just for representation purposes
const MenuPortal = (props) => {
    /* ... */
    return <Portal>{props.children}</Portal>;
};

<Select
    { ... }
    menuPortalTarget={document.body} // needed to activate portaling
    components={{
        MenuPortal
    }}
/>
```

<s>Again, **this is just a theory**, as of writing this answer I could not test this out.</s>

**Edit**: This is not just a theory anymore. I have tested this use case out and created [a working example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/1wnqkk4n8l). I had to copy some functionality from the source code of the `MenuPortal` component just to get the right styles.